# JOOq sparse update

Tags: java, jooq

I am using Jax-RS and Jooq.
I'd like to know how I should implement REST PATCH using sparse data.

Let's say I have some PoJo. I get a JSON PATCH (http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) request with an incomplete object which only contains those fields which are supposed to change.

How would I write such a handler?

I tried accepting the actual Pojo object. My first thought was "if a field is null, i don't update it". This was my first problem.

```
public Resource update(@PathParam("id") UUID id, Resource resource) {
    ResourceRecord record = dslContext.newRecord(RESOURCE, resource);
    dslContext.update(RESOURCE).set(resource).where(RESOURCE.ID.eq(id)).execute();

    // or

    memberDao.update(member);

    return resourceDao.findById(id);
}
```

While trying things and searching online I thought "what about setting something to null deliberately?". So it has to depend on the presence of the field in the request.

My last idea was:

```
public Resource update(@PathParam("id") UUID id, Map<String, Object> changes) {
    dslContext.update(RESOURCE).set(changes).where(RESOURCE.ID.eq(id)).execute();
    return resourceDao.findById(id);
}
```

which does not work, of course (set(Map< Field, ...>)).

But I'm kinda stuck and the interwebz was full of answers for different problems but I didn't find any case where someone tried the same thing.

In my mind I was playing around with reflection and loops which feels some kind of aweful. I'd like to know how I would write that code as easy as possible.

Comment: Just make sure that you don't pass the `Map` (or whichever data structure) unchecked from the client to the DB. This is a security vulnerability. Attackers could guess private DB fields and change them (e.g. admin=true).

Answer (score 0):

> I tried accepting the actual Pojo object. My first thought was "if a field is null, i don't update it". This was my first problem.

That's not how jOOQ works. [The rationale is described in this blog post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/06/28/orms-should-update-changed-values-not-just-modified-ones/). In particular, your specific line of code here:

```
ResourceRecord record = dslContext.newRecord(RESOURCE, resource);
```

Will set all the [`ResourceRecord.changed()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#changed--) flags to `true`, regardless if they are `null` or not (so, regardless if their value has been modified through setting them from the POJO). In terms of REST, this corresponds to `PUT`, much more than to `PATCH`.

This is much better:

```
public Resource update(@PathParam("id") UUID id, Map<String, Object> changes) {
    dslContext.update(RESOURCE)
              .set(translate(RESOURCE, changes))
              .where(RESOURCE.ID.eq(id))
              .execute();
    return resourceDao.findById(id);
}
```

You'll need a `translate()` function that translates your `Map<String, Object>` to a `Map<Field<?>, Object>`, looking up the field names in `RESOURCE`.

This should work out of the box, of course, an is currently inconsistent with remaining API. A fix is on the way: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6388

In the meantime, you can just pass the map to [`DSLContext.newRecord(Table, Object)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord-org.jooq.Table-java.lang.Object-), which will call [`Record.fromMap()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#fromMap-java.util.Map-) internally